# Remove child entity if relationship removed

Tags: objective-c, core-data

There is a containment `OneToOne` relationship `Library -- Boss`:

```
Library --(Cascade)--> Boss
Boss    --(No Action)--> Library
```

Use case: replace boss. Replace means remove old value from database, save new value in database and set new value of the relationship. If I set a new boss and save the context, new boss is inserted, relationship is set to the new boss, but the old boss is not removed, it only gets library key nullified. How would I remove old boss complete from database?

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass NSManagedObject for Boss, and override -(void)willSave, and delete object in that method if necessary.

As a sidenote, in this case you should use Nullify instead of No action. No action causes trouble, and it is rarely useful. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html

Answer (score 0):

So you set the delete rule between library and boss to "cascade", right? 
In that case the boss only gets deleted when there is no other entity referring to boss. Sort of reference counting. Are you sure that there is no record/entity within you database that is currently referring to the boss entity?